# What does "Yeah, you did" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, formality, colloquialisms

This has been a question since I watched the episode [Ted Mosby, Architect](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0858000/) [HIMYM, Season 2] long time back. Yesterday I came across this again and I still don't get it. What does "*Yeah, you did*" actually mean?

Copying the [conversation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0858000/quotes?item=qt2115379) here:

> Marshall: Well, all skyscrapers kinda look like a...
>
> Ted: Marshall, it's a seventy-eight story pink marble tower with a rounded top and two spherical entryways at the front.
>
> Marshall: Wow, so it's the whole package.
>
> Barney: **Yeah, you did**. [fist-bumps Marshall]
>
> Marshall: Had to.
>
> Barney: Oh, dude, if they're selling condos you gotta get me in. And don't give me the shaft.
>
> Marshall: **Yeah, you did**.
>
> Barney: Had to. [they fist-bump again]
>
> Ted: It's a travesty! It's gonna define the skyline of the city. If it was me, I could have designed something amazing. Instead, I'm spending twelve hours a day designing the
> cornices.
>
> Marshall: **Yeah, you did**. [holds out his fist for a bump]
>
> Ted: That wasn't one.

[PS : I am not a native English speaker. I guess I am not so familiar with a lot of colloquial phrases]

Comment: Presumably the whole point of this interaction is to "humorously" show that even one of the native speaker conversants doesn't understand the usage. I've never seen it before, so I've no idea why Ted says the final usage is "incorrect" (I assume *"That wasn't one"* means something like *"The last thing I said does **not** represent a suitable context for this catchphrase"*). Maybe that was just a facetious remark intended to make the point that *nobody* can understand which contexts make sense for the usage. Whatever - I doubt ***I'll*** be adopting it.

Comment: There is an implied “You/I didn’t really just make that joke or imply that topic did you/I  (Because you/I’d have to be really crass to do that”  In the current vernacular: “I didn’t just *go there* did I?”  And then comes the “Yes, I noticed what you just said there” phrase: ***Yeah, you did***  (Yes,  you did just make that joke or make a reference to that crass topic)  in some. Contexts the the implied question could also be “Did I just say that outloud?”  “Yeah you did”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guessed, it is a phrase with a specific meaning, and this is the reference:

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=YEAH%20YOU%20DID%21

> A phrase commonly used by Casey Burns which has rapidly gained widespread use.
>
> It is used to add exclamation when a person states something that is either awesome, innuendo or just plain stupid.
>
> YEAH YOU DID!
>   YEAH I WILL
>   YEAH YOU ARE!
>   YEAH I AM!
>   YEAH I WILL!
>   YEAH I DID!

Comment: Hasn't gained widespread use where I am. Your mileage will vary.

Answer (score 1):

in the HIMYM clip you are referencing, the phrase "yeah you did" refers to making a sexual innuendo as part of a double entendre. When at the end of the exchange, Ted says "that wasn't one." he refers to his use of the word cornices as not having a second meaning.